# Passing value from JQuery Datepicker to code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQuery Datepicker in my .aspx file.

I need to use the date value in my code behind file. This is my function which I want to update a hidden value on my page which I can use in my code behind.

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function () {
            var dueDate= document.getElementById('dueDate');
            dueDate.value = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });
});
```

My hidden value which I want to update, which is on the same .aspx page:

```
<Input id="dueDate" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Now in my code behind, I want to use the date like so:

```
DateTime due= dueDate.Value;
```

This gives me an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
```

I get the same error when I use

```
DateTime due = Convert.ToDateTime(dueDate.Value);
```

What is the correct way to use the date from Datepicker in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having the following code on your .aspx file, removing runat server:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" value="" />
```

Now make the following change in your jquery datepicker function:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        onSelect: function() {
            $("#dueDate").val() = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        }
    });
}
```

This way the hidden field value of dueDate gets updated whenever the value of your datepicker control is changed. Further since your hidden field now has a name and value attribute associated with it, your code behind would receive its value **as a string** whenever your form is posted.

Now in your code behind file, create your DateTime object as follows:

```
string[] dueDateSplit = Request.Form["dueDate"].Split('-');
DateTime due = new DateTime(dueDateSplit[2], dueDateSplit[1], dueDateSplit[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Parse(...)`

or

`DateTime.ParseExact(...)`

or

`DateTime.Parse("01/01 2010");`

or use

`DateTime.TryParse`

if you aren't sure it converts in which type every time, ie. not always a date, so try this 4 and check

Answer (score 1):

Provide a name for the datepicker

```
<Input id="dueDate" name = "dueDate" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

and use the below

```
String text = Page.Request.Form["dueDate"]
```